# I have to display one item in my RecyclerView after every 2 seconds

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am fetching data per one day date from database. and data must show per all days in RecyclerView in (for loop).
But have to showing RecyclerView items  any time after 2 seconds.
But all of items show once together, after reading all data for all days in (for loop).
so..
How can i to display items one by one, in any implementation with (for loop)?
Hope help me.

Comment: by using thread u can achieve it, sleep your thread every 2 seconds and add a new item in the list and refresh your recycle view adapter

Answer (score 1):

just initialize the recycler view with only one item, then count the time with `System.currentTimeMillis();`, after two second add an item in the recyclerView list and call `notifyItemInserted()` to notify the adapter that a new item is inserted.

here a simple pseudocode for this purpose (only to give general idea):

```
long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(now - initialTime < 2000){
    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
//now code after two seconds..
mainList.add(item);
adapter.notifyItemInserted();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and delay binding into apadpter into recycler view..

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final String data = mStringList.get(position);
            if (data == "RED") {
                holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            }
            holder.textView.setText(data);
            holder.firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onItemClick.getPosition(data); // shared data.
                }
            });
        }
    }, 2000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Activity onCreate

```
handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

In Activity

```
 final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.add(listItem);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }
};
```

In Adapter

```
 public void add(ListItem listItem) {
    list.add(listItem);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```